# RxScala: How to keep the thread doing Observable.interval alive?

Tags: multithreading, scala, rx-java, rx-scala

I am trying to write a simple RxScala program:

```
import rx.lang.scala.Observable

import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
import scala.language.{implicitConversions, postfixOps}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val o = Observable.interval(1 second)
    o.subscribe(println(_))
  }
}
```

When I run this program, I do not see anything printed out. I suspect that this is because that thread producing the numbers in `Observable.interval` dies. I noticed a call to `waitFor(o)` in the [RxScalaDemo](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxScala/blob/0.x/examples/src/test/scala/rx/lang/scala/examples/RxScalaDemo.scala#L85), but I can't figure out where that is imported from.

How do I keep this program running for ever printing the number sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not seeing anything because your `main` method exits immediately after you subscribe to the `Observable`. At that point, your program is done.

A common trick for test programs like this is to read a byte from stdin once you've subscribed.

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way to block the main thread from exiting:

```
val o = Observable.interval(1 second)
val latch = new CountDownLatch(1)
o.subscribe(i => {
  print(i)
  if (i >= 5) latch.countDown()

})
latch.await()
```

This is a fairly common pattern, use `CountDownLatch.await` to block the main thread and then countDown the latch when you are done with what you are doing, thus releasing the main thread