# Rx (Reactive Extensions for Java) Zip operator with time interval

Tags: java, multithreading, reactive-programming, rx-java

I am relatively new to RxJava, and I have been playing around with operators for a while.

I saw this small example that emits items after short intervals (1s):

```
Observable<String> data = Observable.just("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
    Observable.zip(data, Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), (d, t) -> {
        return d + " " + t;
    }).toBlocking().forEach(System.out::println);
```

This works, but when I remove `toBlocking()` that turns the source into a BlockingObservable, the program executes and ends with no output.

I usually look at the marble diagrams to understand things properly: 
http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

In the last sentence it says: *It will only emit as many items as the number of items emitted by the source Observable that emits the fewest items.*

Does that mean, the `data` Observable emits all items in less than 1 second and ends before printing the first two items from each Observable? Because each Observable is asynchronous by itself?

I need a clear understanding of what's happening, and if there are other ways to deal with similar cases. Anyone?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29440107/2599745

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Observable.interval` uses a `Scheduler` under the covers. It will be emitting from another thread. Meanwhile, the main thread has done all its composing and will exit. Presumably you have this code in a `main` method, which is why your program is exiting.

In a real system this shouldn't be a problem (unless your real system is a `main` method with this code in it).

In an example program, you can cause the main thread to block by reading a byte from stdin. Something like this:

```
Observable<String> data = Observable.just("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
Observable.zip(data, Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), (d, t) -> d + " " + t)
        .subscribe(System.out::println);

System.in.read();
```

Comment: Also, you might want to take a look at the non-static ```Observable.zipWith```. It's more fluent.

Comment: So this is not about being asynchronous, it's just that timers run on a different thread and the zip(With) operator(s) do not emit until both of them emit their first items..?

Comment: Yes - ```zip``` produces an ```Observable``` that doesn't emit anything until both of the zipped Observables have emitted something.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially your main program is exiting before the observable has a chance to emit anything, that is the reason why you are not seeing any output. The way to fix it will be to block in some way until the `Observable` has emitted all items, here is one way using a `CountDownLatch`:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
Observable<String> data = Observable.just("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
Observable.zip(data, Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS), (d, t) -> {
    return d + " " + t;
}).finallyDo(latch::countDown).forEach(System.out::println);

latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: this is nice. How is it different from toBlocking()?

Comment: Well, both do the same thing, in the sense that both would block until Observable has a chance to emit, but do it in different ways. The first way by calling `toBlocking` you are creating a different type altogether `BlockingObservable` and thus the underlying behavior is changed. In the second way you are using `Observable` itself but giving it a chance to emit items by using a latch. This is purely for test either way, for a real system you should not use either of the approaches